# Postgres script an easier way

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm wondering if there is an easier way to write the query below. In a nutshell the outcome of the query is to sum all the oscar awards the movie Titanic has won and the awards are contained in different tables. This script works but seems convoluted.

```
SELECT title, production_year, 
COUNT(*) + (crew.c + director.c + writer.c + actor.c) AS Oscars
FROM movie_award, 
(SELECT COUNT(*) AS c
    FROM crew_award 
    WHERE result = 'won'
    AND title = 'Titanic'
    AND award_name = 'Oscar') AS crew,
(SELECT COUNT(*) AS c
    FROM director_award
    WHERE result = 'won'
    AND title = 'Titanic'
    AND award_name = 'Oscar') AS director,
(SELECT COUNT(*) AS c
    FROM writer_award
    WHERE result = 'won'
    AND title = 'Titanic'
    AND award_name = 'Oscar') AS writer,
(SELECT COUNT(*) AS c
    FROM actor_award
    WHERE result = 'won'
    AND title = 'Titanic'
    AND award_name = 'Oscar') AS actor
WHERE result = 'won'
AND title = 'Titanic'
AND award_name = 'Oscar'
GROUP BY crew.c, director.c, writer.c, actor.c, title, production_year;
```

Comment: It'd be rather more useful if you'd show the tables and data. Was this downloaded from somewhere? Can you create a summary http://sqlfiddle.com/?

Comment: No I wrote it and it's very easy to see the attributes that are needed from the script.

Comment: @Bob Wrong attitude.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A bit hard to give a "run as is" answer without seeing the schema, but you should be able to use UNION ALL to simplify things somewhat, something like;

```
SELECT title, production_year, COUNT(*) Oscars
FROM ( 
  SELECT title, production_year, result, award_name FROM movie_award
  UNION ALL
  SELECT title, production_year, result, award_name FROM crew_award
  UNION ALL
  SELECT title, production_year, result, award_name FROM director_award
  UNION ALL
  SELECT title, production_year, result, award_name FROM writer_award
  UNION ALL
  SELECT title, production_year, result, award_name FROM actor_award
)z
WHERE result = 'won' AND title = 'Titanic' AND award_name = 'Oscar'
GROUP BY title, production_year;
```